# ErrorActionPreference ignored for dotnet when using Right-Click > Run with Powershell

Tags: powershell, .net-core

Take the following script example:

```
$ErrorActionPreference = "Stop";
dotnet "SomeErrorSomeDLL.dll"
Write-Host "Error Did Not Stop The File!";
pause;
```

Observe that when running this in PowerShell IDE, the script stops successfully and the `Write-Host` nor `pause` command are ever executed.

Right click the same script and click "Run with Powershell"

Observe that the script does not stop and the `Write-Host` and `pause` command are both executed.

Could someone explain what would cause this behavior?

Comment: When you have interactive PowerShell host which own console window and error output of native application is not redirected, then PowerShell engine patch `stdout` of native application directly to its own `stdout` bypassing PowerShell engine, and by doing so it loose ability to acknowledge `stdout` output from native application.